# React Flux Webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, flux

Trying to build an extremely simple CRUD app with Flux.  Why is this console.log not working in my ServerStore.js register function?  It seems like webpack is not even bundling it?

ServerStore.js

```
var AppDispatcher = require('../dispatcher/dispatcher');
var AppConstants = require('../actions/constants');
var assign = require('react/lib/Object/assign');
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

var CHANGE_EVENT = 'change';

var ServerStore = assign(EventEmitter.prototype, {
    emitChange: function(){
    this.emit(CHANGE_EVENT)
},
addChangeListener:function(callback){
    this.on(CHANGE_EVENT, callback)
},
removeChangeListener: function(callback){
    this.removeListener(CHANGE_EVENT, callback)
},


});
AppDispatcher.register(function(payload){
    var action = payload.action;
    console.log('hhhhhhhhhhh'); //<----------------NOT WORKING!

});
```

Dispatcher.js

```
var Dispatcher = require('flux').Dispatcher;
var assign = require('react/lib/Object.assign');

var AppDispatcher = assign(new Dispatcher(), {
    handleViewAction: function(action){
        console.log('action', action)//<------THIS WORKS OK!
        this.dispatch({
        source:'VIEW_ACTION',
        action: action
      })
   }
});

module.exports = AppDispatcher;
```

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports ={
   entry: "./app-client.js",
   output: {
       filename: "public/bundle.js" 
   },
module:{
    loaders:[
        {
            exclude: /(node_modules|app-server.js)/,
            loader: 'babel'
        }
    ]
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you aren't actually exporting the *dispatcher* itself, rather the *actions*. Try separating the dispatcher and actions. This way you can also create new sets of actions and re-use the dispatcher when needed.

*Dispatcher.js*

```
var Dispatcher = require('flux').Dispatcher;

module.exports = new Dispatcher();
```

*AppActions.js*

```
var AppDispatcher = require('../dispatcher/Dispatcher');

var AppActions = {

    handleViewAction: function(data) {
        AppDispatcher.dispatch({
            actionType: 'VIEW_ACTION',
            data: data
        });
        console.log('VIEW_ACTION dispatched.')
    }

};

module.exports = AppActions;
```

Answer (score 0):

**React with Flux** here is my github repository hope it will helps to understand the basic of react with flux https://github.com/TameshwarNirmalkar/ES6Babel it has:

- Webpack
- ES6
- Babel
- Eslint
- React
- Flux
- Json-server for rest api complete
- CRUD operation

Hope it would be helpful.